# Send grid trimmed message for a link

Tags: sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

when I create a html code for send with php to an email with SendGrid and I add a link like aquí the email arrives with the text *[Trimmed message] View entire message* and I don't know how can I delete this message from my emails send with html and SendGrid

This is an example of html code that I need send

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    
    <html lang="es">
    
    <head>
    
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    
    <title>Solicitud de cierre de mesa de regalos</title>
    
    
    
    <style>
    
        div.mailBody{
    
            color: black;
    
            text-align: left;
    
            background: white;
    
            font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    
            padding: 60px;
    
        }
    
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    
            div.mailBody{
    
                padding: 20px;
    
            }
    
        }
    
        .mailBody span,.mailBody li,.mailBody p,.mailBody label,.mailBody h1,.mailBody h2{
    
            color: black;
    
        }
    
        .title{
    
            text-align: center;
    
        }
    
        .center{
    
            text-align: center;
    
        }
    
        div.container{
    
            margin-top: 20px;
    
        }
    
        div.cardMail{
    
            border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    
            padding: 25px;
    
            box-shadow: 2px 5px #d9d9d9;
    
        }
    
    </style>

</head>

<body>

<div class="mailBody">

    <div class="cardMail"> 

        <center><img class="" style="margin-bottom: 20px; width:250px;" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1292/2935/files/LOGO_cantia_change.png?v=1643318474"/></center>

        <div class="container">

            <h1 class="title">Solicitud de cierre de mesa de regalos</h1>

            <p class="center">

                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In ultricies accumsan dignissim. Vivamus vulputate bibendum rhoncus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec non ligula est. Cras sollicitudin at lacus eu rhoncus. Etiam fringilla fringilla augue. Aenean ut mauris leo. Aliquam imperdiet eros quis luctus mollis. Vestibulum consectetur ipsum a elit blandit, a commodo justo ultrices.



                Sed sit amet sapien metus. Cras id fermentum quam. Curabitur tempor malesuada condimentum. Mauris metus purus, mattis sed neque eget, dapibus ornare ex. Morbi fermentum elit sed tincidunt finibus. Nunc et pharetra lacus. Nulla ut euismod massa. Etiam iaculis, elit ut mattis ornare, ipsum risus scelerisque risus, non vestibulum lorem nibh id urna. Quisque euismod porttitor risus eget dictum.

                

                Nam ut purus ligula. Nunc malesuada congue augue et maximus. In dictum gravida sagittis. Mauris condimentum risus neque, id egestas augue egestas eget. Praesent pretium tellus a massa euismod congue. Aenean efficitur turpis vel libero feugiat cursus. Sed finibus dignissim nisi, sit amet dictum quam congue vel.

                

                Sed ullamcorper id ipsum at dapibus. Nunc quis tincidunt ex, et tristique tellus. Proin euismod vel mi vel lobortis. Phasellus mollis ipsum quis porta hendrerit. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Morbi iaculis volutpat risus, in lobortis libero pharetra a. Aliquam sollicitudin cursus ligula, nec varius purus euismod non. Sed aliquam fringilla interdum. Nullam quis orci fermentum, tincidunt libero eu, feugiat ligula. In vel arcu aliquam, finibus magna et, lacinia leo. Nulla fringilla magna finibus vestibulum molestie. Curabitur massa purus, porttitor accumsan mauris et, rutrum sagittis mauris.

                Puedes revisar tu estado de cuenta <a  href="https://cantia.com.mx/apps/giftregistry/registry/idMesa">aquí</a>.

            </p>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

I tried to send many emails and with differents especials characters and I discoverd the problem is the link ""

I want that message *[Trimmed message] View entire message*  disappear

Answer (score 0):

The clipping is happening by the email clients such as Gmail, Outlook, etc. and is not controlled by SendGrid. If you don't want to have your emails clipped, you'll have to figure out why these email clients are clipping them, and adjusting your email if possible at all.

According to [this article](https://www.bitrecover.com/blog/gmail-view-entire-message/), Gmail clips emails bigger than 102KB in size. I'm not sure this is 100% accurate tho. Is your email below that size, and if not, can you try reducing the size to see if that's the issue?